# Why doesn't a switch use the destination MAC addresses of outgoing frames for MAC learning?

Tags: networking, mac-address

> Usually, a switch can populate its MAC address table automatically by
>   learning the source MAC addresses of incoming frames on each port.

I found the above sentence in the following reference:

[04-Layer 2 - LAN Switching Configuration Guide](http://www.h3c.com/portal/Technical_Support___Documents/Technical_Documents/Switches/H3C_S12500_Series_Switches/Configuration/Operation_Manual/H3C_S12500_CG-Release1335-5W130/04/201108/722516_1285_0.htm)

Why doesn't a switch use the destination MAC address of outgoing frames for MAC learning?

I think it's useful for preventing flooding in some situation which I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't a switch use the destination MAC addresses of outgoing frames for MAC learning.

**Short answer:** Because it's pointless to learn from destination mac-addresses

**Long answer:**
A switch learns two things from the *source mac-address* when an ethernet frame is sent:

- The value of the mac-address of the ethernet NIC attached that that cable
- The number of the port which has the aforementioned mac-address

Destination mac-addresses don't provide useful information for a switch to learn from.  When a PC sends an ethernet frame somewhere, the switch must deliver to that destination mac-address.  Learning a mac-addresses' existence and location coincidental to the delivery event is a broken algorithm.

Comment: Now I realize my question is nonsense. Thank you for the explanation :-)